# How can I get rid of the "+You" tab on every single page from Google?

Tags: google, google-plus

I've just been forced to leave Google Plus and Google Profile. As such, I'd like to *not* have "+You" leading every single page from Google.

[image]

Is there any way to do so without resorting on client side modifications?

Comment: Damn you for preliminarily excluding my obligatory Greasemonkey solution. ;)

Comment: Damn you for making me notice that +You tab. "+You"?  Sounds vaguely insulting doesn't it?  Well +You back Google!

Comment: Since it's key to Google's new social initiative, I highly doubt they're going to offer a way to turn it off. I think you're stuck with client-side solutions.

Comment: @hheimbuerger I'm sorry, but so long as Chrome fails to sync extensions for me that solution would be pretty partial.

Comment: I really don't see what the big deal is, why not just leave it how it is? I mean it's only another link after all, you'll get used to it being there soon enough.

Comment: It's worse when you wanting to get an account but your under 18 and there's a plus +you button mocking you on every google page. And a big blue arrow on the google homepage

Answer (score 1):

When you have Firefox I can really recommend you this addon:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remove-it-permanently/

Just right click on the +You tab, go to "RIP Advanced" and click "Remove from this domain". Then right click the +You tab again and click "Remove this permanently".

It works for Google Web and Images so when the +You tab appears again (like in Google Maps or Videos) just click "Remove this permanently" again. And there you have a +You tab-free Google. ;)

Comment: Add-ons count as client side modifications I think

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, but still had to +1 it. Nice add-on, thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily removed using the Adblock add-on in Google Chrome browser. Just right click, then to Adblock and remove ad. Done.

Comment: So you're saying that the +1 on the bar can be removed by using Adblock extension to Chrome browser? Adblock is an extension, not a plug-in, correct? Thanks.